# Multiple selection

Tags: usability, multi-selection, pricing

I'm working on a checkout process for a translation service company.

The user originally has one English document that they want to translate into two (or more different languages). However, they are price sensitive, so they wants to choose the different translation quality for each language.

I came up with this solution:
[image]

However, I'm not a big fan of sliders since they require quite some mental work from the user.

Do you guys have any idea how I could make this selection more straight-forward?

Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: @musefan, Amazing! That was my second choice, but I imagined having the final price + price per word in each square. In my case, the screen would be too crowded with all the prices, and it would be hard to swallow. But in your case, it looks excellent! I didn't think I could still have the final price in the last column. What I like in your case is also that price of each type is visible all the time. In that case, the user can compare the prices, which makes his decision easier. *Different rates are because of a different kind of translation. The first type is machine translation, the second

Comment: I like your solutions so far, though I wonder how many languages you will support at a maximum since this could cause your slider thumbs to be at a greater distance from the column header. Maybe you can include 'Type n" inside the thumb somehow?

Comment: This looks like a plea for us to do your work for you, not any Question; certainly not multiple selection or SE User Experience. 

I'm sorry to be the one to say so, and little of what you Posted works in English.

"I'm doing the checkout process for a translation service company" isn't incomprehensible. So what?

Your example does not work in place of "The user has an English document which he wants to translate into two or more other languages…" If you do not you see the difference, please say why.

How does price affecting translation quality affect language?

Answer (score 15):

I actually think your slider idea is not that bad and might be interesting.

Depending on how effortless the implementation has to be, it can also be a simple dropdown in the end:

[image]

---

### Edit

Ok, in response to your comment. How about adding a button with an overlay that explains it all in detail. In comparison to a tooltip, this would work well on mobile as well!

I just added a random graphic there, but it could show the 4 types in a cool way that makes it clear where the differences are.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, that is also an AMAZING idea, however...

Comment: Wow, that is an AMAZING idea, however...

I forgot to mention, that I was planning to explain on mouse hover what each translation type actually is - they are quite complicated to explain therefore is a lot of text and I don't know yet how I would explain each translation type  in the dropdown. Maybe with a dropdown tooltip, but they are not so common and I think there won't be enough space to explain what it means.

Comment: @JakaSmid I updated my answer, maybe that's an option for you.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to avoid the sliders, you can just opt for a very simple grid of checkboxes/radio buttons.

Something like this:

[image]

This makes it very easy for the user to understand exactly which options they are selecting for each language. I suggest adding some additional styling to the selected options to ensure they stand out from the non-selected options.

You *could* make an argument that there is repeated text in each box (via the "types"), although I don't think there is enough repeated text for this to cause a problem for the user. However, if you prefer you could move the "types" labels to be column headers, similar to what you have done with them in your example.

Comment: Given that they said "I'm doing the checkout process for a translation service company", I don't think OP gets to decide on the rates and pricing. Either way, there is a lot of difference in possible translation quality even with 100% standard spelling and grammar. I imagine cheaper options would result in more straight-forward translations, that may have awkward sentence structures and read less naturally, for example. The most expensive options might include additional content editing and generally more time taken by the translator to fine-tune everything.

Comment: take an example: the [La Disparition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Void) novel contains no E in the original French and the translated English version. Other translations follow the same restriction which costs obviously more money. The cheapest solution is to translate just literally. Many books with good puns also need much more time to translate

Comment: @Jasmijn: I understand how different service levels could be done, it is more I don't understand the use-cases of the customers. I am struggling to think of an example (other than personal use) where you would want to compromise on the quality and accuracy.

Comment: "If you want to avoid the sliders" — which you should, musefan's answer here is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody will use calculator to select right *price* for translation to achieve total acceptable order amount. The first step is set all languages to maximal price and watching if final cost is acceptable. If not - the next step is lowering price of the most *unimportant* language. And so on. So we need to provide ability to easyly relocate languages between prices (or your translation Types). This couls be done by grouping translations by Type.

Initial grouping:

---

**Total: 30.00*

| Language | Type 5 |
| --- | --- |
| German | 0.10 |
| Chinese | 0.20 |
|  | **Type 4** |
|  | **Type 3** |
|  | **Type 4** |
|  | **Type 1** |

Relocate one language to reduce total cost:

---

**Total: 25.00*

| Language | Type 5 |
| --- | --- |
| German | 0.10 |
|  | **Type 4** |
| Chinese | 0.15 |
|  | **Type 3** |
|  | **Type 4** |
|  | **Type 1** |

---

And so on. You may add much more elements to improve usability, e.g. theoretical total cost for every Type to give user estimations for better choices (see below), or add group relocations, etc. Or even automatically group languages for user according his desired final budget.

---

**Total: 25.00*

| Language | Type 5 | (max 30.00) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| German | 0.10 |  |
|  | **Type 4** | (max 23.00) |
| Chinese | 0.15 |  |
|  | **Type 3** | (max 20.00) |
|  | **Type 4** | (max 15.00) |
|  | **Type 1** | (max 7.00) |